# Right terminology: Call the ordering module? Use the ordering module? Constrain a set with the ordering module?

Tags: alloy

I have an Alloy model that uses the ordering module:

```
open util/ordering[House]
```

I am writing up a description of my model. What is the correct terminology to use when describing the above expression? Currently I say this:

```
Call the ordering module with the set of houses.
```

But I don't think that is correct. I don't think a model "calls" a module. What is the right terminology?

Comment: Apply seems applicable here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the description as follows:

```
Enforces the set of Houses to be ordered using the util/ordering module
```

The terminology you might seek is that you are importing the module util/ordering with the signature House passed as argument.